# Expectation on property getter/setter in python with Doubles

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using [doubles](https://doubles.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) together with pytest to unit test some Python 2.7 code.

Let's say I have a class such as:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, value):
        pass
```

And that I have some code where an instance of `Foo` is injected and that invokes `method`:

```py
def do_bar(foo):
    foo.bar(22)
```

I know how to create an expectation

```py
def test_doing_bar_sets_bar_to_22():
    foo = Foo()
    expect(foo).bar(22)
    do_bar(foo)
```

But I wonder how I can create an expectation on a setter of a property defined with the `@property` decorator:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        pass

    @property
    def bee(self):
        pass

    @bee.setter
    def bee(self, value):
        pass

def do_bee(foo):
    foo.bee = 22
```

To make this work:

```py
def test_doing_bee_sets_bee_to_22():
    foo = Foo()
    # Something like expect(foo.bee).setter(22)
    # I tried: expect(foo.__class__.bee).setter(foo, 22)
    do_bee(foo)
```

I know I could simply create a class with a `bee` property that captures the value and pass that instance to the `do_bee` method, but if it is possible to resolve it through the `expect` approach, I prefer it for symmetry with the rest of the code and expressiveness.

Is it possible to do this with *doubles*?

**UPDATE 2019-01-24**
I did some research in the source code of doubles:

https://github.com/uber/doubles/blob/master/doubles/proxy_property.py

https://github.com/uber/doubles/blob/master/doubles/proxy_method.py

I believe ProxyProperty implementation will not allow creating allowances/expectations when the property has a setter. In particular, I believe the `__set__` should be implemented, but I don't totally understand *how property allowances/expectations* is supposed to work (from a design perspective).

I could get it to work by changing the `ProxyProperty` implementation to:

```py
class ProxyProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, name, original):
        self._name = name
        self._original = original

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return obj.__dict__.get(self._name, self._original.__get__(obj, objtype))

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self._name] = value
```

(Also in the `proxy_method.ProxyMethod._hijack_target` I remove the `self._target.obj.__dict__[double_name(self._method_name)] = self` since it does no longer makes sense to me after my changes).

With those changes I can write:

```py
def test_doing_bee_sets_bee_to_22():
    foo = Foo()
    allow(foo).bee
    do_bee(foo)
    assert foo.bee == 22
```

However I'd prefer to have a mechanism such as with_args() because that would allow creating multiple expectations if for example doo_bee set foo.bee multiple times.

**UPDATE 2019-02-23**
I opened an [issue](https://github.com/uber/doubles/issues/141) in their Github page and they recently marked it as a bug.